# ROWNUM query return

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting used to rownum and am trying to understand the logic.

For instance, if a 'Department' tables contains more than 10 rows, and we run a query that says:

```
Select * from Department 
where Rownum between 1 and 7
```

How many rows will this query return?

Comment: In Oracle it will return 7 rows.

Comment: In SQL, would it return 6?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sql-Server is the RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select top 7 ... 
from Department 
order by some_field
```

without rownum in where
or use ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
with
  dep as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by some_field) as lp, d.*
  from Department d)
select * from dep where lp between 1 and 7
```